# Bulky macro definition overload

Tags: c++, c, macros

I want to define macro like

```
#define DECLARE_FUNCTION(funcName, retType, args) retType funcName(args)
```

And use it like

```
DECLARE_FUNCTION(intFunc, int, void);
DECLARE_FUNCTION(voidFunc, void, double, double);
DECLARE_FUNCTION(doubleFunc, double, int, double, double);
```

expecting that those will expand to

```
int intFunc(void);
void voidFunc(double, double);
double doubleFunc(int, double, double);
```

This is certainly not working, as macro defined with three arguments eats all the “redundant” arguments and result is

```
int intFunc(void);
void voidFunc(double);
double doubleFunc(int);
```

I don’t mind defining macros for different cases, like 
`DECLARE_FUNCTION_WITH_0_ARGS`, `DECLARE_FUNCTION_WITH_1_ARG`, `DECLARE_FUNCTION_WITH_2_ARGS`, etc. But the problem is that these macros are not as primitive as I gave in the example, they contain a lot of lines of code, and it would be nice not to rewrite them, but to define only one nontrivial macro, e.q. `DECLARE_FUNCTION_WITH_1_ARG`, and call it from bodies of all other macros.

Comment: Perhaps this would help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a variable number of arguments in your macro. They can be accessed by using special symbols like `__VA_ARGS__` inside the macro.

Here's the syntax in standard C.

```
#define DECLARE_FUNCTION(funcName, retType, ...) retType funcName(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The `...` stands for all the dynamic arguments and is accessed by `__VA_ARGS__`. Note that you need at least one dynamic argument, otherwise you get a compiler error.

GNU C++ introduces extensions to prevent this from happening. So you can alternatively declare the above as:

```
#define DECLARE_FUNCTION(funcName, retType, ...) retType funcName(##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Here are some examples:

`DECLARE_FUNCTION(func1, void)` becomes `void func1()` (only with extensions).

`DECLARE_FUNCTION(func2, int, int, char)` becomes `int func2(int, char)`

This feature is called "variadic macros". You can read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Comment: Not detailed enough to answer the op's question. Perhaps expand your answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There is literally nothing else other than using the __VA_ARGS__ symbol. However, I will edit the answer to give some links to documentation and further reading. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think there is, seeing how the macro should expand to a function declaration and the return type, name and parameters are passed to the macro as arguments. Please post some example code.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore there you are :)